# Change from O(n^2) complexity to O(n) complexity or lower for a piece of code used in multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

I have a piece of code as follows. I want to improve time complexity for this.
This is a thread and I can have upto maximum of 2000 threads that execute this function at the same time

On top of that, I wait for file descriptors that are ready from a pollset. MAX_RTP_SESSIONS is also huge (value of 5000 or more). so its a big for loop and therefore i can see performance getting affected.  [When value of MAX_RTP_SESSIONS is reduced to just 500, i can see a huge improvement in performance]

But i will have to use 2000 threads and also 5000 sessions. I wish i could find a way to change time complexity from o(n^2) to atleast o(n) or better. Any ideas are really appreciated!

```
//..
retval=epoll_wait(epfd, pollset, EPOLL_MAX_EVENTS, mSecTimeout)
//..

sem_wait(&sem_sessions);

for(i = 0; i< retVal; i++) {  
    for (j=0; j < MAX_RTP_SESSIONS; j++) {
        if ((g_rtp_sessions[j].destroy==FALSE) &&
        (g_rtp_sessions[j].used!=FALSE) &&
        (g_rtp_sessions[j].p_rtp->rtp_socket->fd == pollset[i].data.fd))
        {
            if (0 < rtp_recv_data(....)) {
                rtp_update(...)
            }
        }
    }
}

sem_post(&sem_sessions);

//..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort `pollset`, then you can do a binary search on it which should lead to a O(n log n) algorithm.

Comment: Hi sebastien, Thanks for your reply. Instead of sorting pollset, I can sort and do a binary search on g_rtp_sessions right? since retVal returned is only < 100 whereas, MAX_RTP_SESSIONS can be 5000 or even 10000.